# Does IF work with a range, or only single cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm getting inconsistent results with: {=IF(E28:I28<>0,AK28,AK28+D28)} sometimes a correct answer, but not always.

but =IF(OR(E28<>0,F28<>0,G28<>0,H28<>0,I28<>0,),AK28,AK28+D28) works fine.

My spreadsheet has has 31 columns of data, so the IF/OR formula is very lengthy. Will IF not test a range?

Comment: The array formula returns an array where each element is either AK28 or AK28+D28, depending on the corresponding value of the single cell from E28 to I28. If you meant to say "if any cell is non zero", that would be `if(countif(E28:I28, "<>0") > 0)`.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg for the explanation of what my formula was really doing. I'm trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use sum to sum the cells first.

```
=IF(SUM(E28:I28)<>0,AK28,AK28+D28)
```

But if one cell is `-10` and one is `10` then the sum will be 0.
Is that correct for your needs or does it have to be each cell <>0?

Comment: You're correct that a SUM would not work. I need to check each cell to make sure it is <>0.

Comment: In that case look at what GSerg posted as a comment